# How to change bluetooth device class

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth

I am trying to change my advertised bluetooth device class from computer to phone, running ubuntu 12.04. I downloaded the bluez sources and edited the main.conf file to change the line

```
Class = 0x000100
```

to something else. I used

```
Class = 0x0c025a
```

Then I ran make && make install. I think that works ok because the `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` file has been updated with my changes.

Now, the problem is that when I actually try to connect to a device

```
hcitool cc <bdaddr>
```

I see that I am still advertising myself using the Class `0x000100` and not `0x0c025a`.

What am I missing here to get this changes to take effect?

Answer (score 11):

First, find your interface name:

```
hciconfig
```

It should give you the name of the interface, e.g., `hci0`.

Given that display your interface class:

```
hciconfig hci0 class
```

That should display your device class.

Finally, with super user privilege:

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 class 000408
```

should set up new class of your device.

A useful reference of bluetooth classes with hexadecimal and binary representations can be found here:
http://www.question-defense.com/tools/class-of-device-bluetooth-cod-list-in-binary-and-hex

Answer (score 2):

The BlueZ `hostname` plugin overrides the `Name` and `Class` settings in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`. Follow these steps to specify the Bluetooth Class of Device (CoD):

1. Skip loading the `hostname` plugin when starting the bluetooth daemon by modifying `/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service`. Example:

   ```
   sudo sed -i 's/bluetoothd/bluetoothd \-\-noplugin=hostname/g' /lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service
   ```

Alternatively you can specify an inclusion list using `--plugin=<plugins>`. See `bluetoothd(8)` and https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/plugins

2. Edit `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` and specify `Class` in the General section. Specify `Name` as well if you want something other than `BlueZ X.YZ`:

   ```
   [General]
   Class = 0x1c0420
   Name = UbuntuCarAudio
   ```
3. Reboot or restart the bluetooth service for the changes to take effect:

   ```
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   sudo service bluetooth restart
   ```
4. Verify the changes by running `hciconfig -a` or `echo 'show' | bluetoothctl`. `hciconfig -a` will show you the decoded Class of Device (CoD) information:

   ```
   Name: 'UbuntuCarAudio'
   Class: 0x1c0420
   Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer
   Device Class: Audio/Video, Car Audio
   ```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer, while it does work fine for the Name, the Class doesn't get overridden anymore, instead it's set to 0x000000. Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: @cfz42 I have seen the Service Classes bits get ignored, but I don't know what causes this - maybe BlueZ inspection of running services? You could try using hciconfig, e.g `sudo hciconfig hci0 class 1c0420`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change class name in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf file.

```
Class = 0x00041C
```

Then restart bluetooth service

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

Then turn off your bluetooth from top panel icon and turn it on.